# 2 NIC, 2 DNS & Access Point

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

Im running a computer with Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter at home. NIC number one is used for hosting a website. I plugged in another NIC and connected it to the network aswell. Then I plugged in my WiFi adapter and made it an access point that uses the connection of the second NIC I just installed. All of the network cards have default settings but I wanted to start using a SmartDNS Service and put the 2 DNS addresses into the second NIC that is used by the wireless adapter that acts as an access point. Now when I connect to the access point with my Roku 3, it doesnt use that second NIC's DNS and the SmartDNS wont work. It is somehow using the first NICs DNS and I cant understand why so. It feels as if the WiFi adapter isnt using the correct NIC even though I have checked multiple times that it actually is using the correct NIC.

Why is this so that I cannot have separate DNS settings on 2 separate NICs and make it work properly? For some reason always the DNS settings of the first NIC are being used even though Im sharing the connection of the second NIC with special DNS info for the WiFi adapter. Is this type of setup even possible that Im talking about or am I doing something completely wrong?